# Core Data iPhone App - Updating records in production stage

Tags: core-data, production-environment, updating

I'm currently working on my first Core Data iPhone App and would like your opinion on how to update records/doing general maintenance in a production stage after app has been approved.

All the public scenes will of course be available to users, but a few scenes where "only admins" can access must be private or protected against public access. What the best strategy you find on this? I am thinking for example, inserting a log-in & password scene in between let's say, the main table-view and the edit/add new rows scene to update a new row or label title for example.

How to push those updates so the changes can be re-deployed to the production app(App store) How about a external source like a server based solution to submit updates? How do you update the persistent store in that case? I have

This app is a simple table-view list of workshop training sessions for teachers(i.e, Math 101, Algebra I, Algebra I, Advanced Algebra, etc..) where people can write a feedback note after they attended the session on a detail view scene by clicking on any of the rows.

Thanks so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should avoid using "back doors" in your apps. Keep all the controllers that are not for the user completely *removed* from the production target.

As for future changes in your data model, once you get more familiar with the Core Data API you will discover that what you want to do is quite simple.

As for the update of the data model - in all but the most complicated cases it can be completely automatic. Just version your data model, make sure the automatic migration option is enabled when you add the persistent store, and you can simply update your production app with a new version on the app store - all migration will be done for you automatically.